# "Do you watch X" vs "Did you watch X"

Tags: past-tense, present-continuous

So when you ask someone

> Do you watch X?

you ask if X is still running, right? If it has stopped premiering, then does the question rephrase to

> Did you watch X?

?

Answer (score 2):

**Do you watch X?**
- I would expect that this refers to a TV series that is still running.

**Did you watch X?**
- I would expect that the series (or event such as a sports game or awards show) ran and concluded.

**Have you watched X?**
- I would expect that this refers to either a movie or TV series, either ongoing or concluded. I would especially expect this to be common when referring to TV shows/series on platforms like Netflix where whole seasons may be uploaded at once and people aren't watching as one audience at a specific time.

Answer (score 0):

Concerning the second sentence, if we are talking about a TV series which has stopped running then I would choose the structure "used to watch" in order to show the contrast to the present situation.

"Did you use to watch X?" ( when it was running) Thank you.